# Content Type column shared between libraries, meta missing when document is transfered

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

Sorry if this is a little long winded.

So I have two Document Libraries. A **"Drop Off"** (**Not** the one from the *Content Organizer Site feature*, just a lib called "Drop Off") and **"Resting"** library.

The site has a Content Type that is inherited from the Content Type hub. This Content Type is then extended on the site to add an additional Lookup column **"Employee"** this Extended Content Type is then shared between the libraries mentioned above.

In the **"Drop Off"**, I plug the meta data in, I.E. the **"Employee"** col, and once that is complete I have a *2013 Workflow* that moves the document to the **"Resting"** library.

Now, on other sites this works just fine, no issue. On this one site I have, all the other meta data is stable across the library, but the "Employee" field does not come over.

If I manually move the file back to the **Drop Off**, the data is there, then if I move it back to **Resting**, it's missing again. Almost as if they were really two separate columns. But I don't think this is the case as when I pull up the Site Setting Columns in parallel, the "Employee" col indicates that it is a part of the Content Type shared betwix the libraries.

Has anyone seen this before? Advice? Questions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this works on my end. No metadata missing. Please check the following:

1. Make sure you have added the content type to the "Drop Off" library and "Resting" library.
2. Try to remove the column then re-add it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, the same content type is on both libs. If I delete the Column on the resting library, wont I lose all the data that is currently on the documents already at rest with that column filled in?